# Handling wrong contract type in JSON.NET

Tags: json.net

Is it possible to skip a part of json when contract type does not match. Namely, I receive a json response which does not conform the schema - null objects are serialized as empty arrays ("thank's" to php serializer). So, instead of  "null" or "{}" I get "[]".

So far, I tried to use Error event handler available in JsonSerializerSettings. However, this approach is rather ugly because Json.net does not return meaningful exception type.

**Example of valid response:**

```
{
    "key": "key",
    "id": "id",
    "status": "status",
    "opts": {
        "start": 42,
        "limit": 12
        }
    }
}
```

**Example of invalid response**

```
{
    "key": "key",
    "id": "id",
    "status": "status",
    "opts": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this issue using a custom `JsonConverter`.  The converter can detect the format of the `opts` property in the JSON and then either deserialize it or set its value to null in the target object.  Here's how I would write the converter:

```
class OptsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Opts));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            return new Opts
            {
                start = (int)token["start"],
                limit = (int)token["limit"]
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string valid = @"
        {
            ""key"": ""key"",
            ""id"": ""id"",
            ""status"": ""status"",
            ""opts"": {
                ""start"": 42,
                ""limit"": 12
            }
        }";

        DeserializeAndWriteToConsole(valid);

        string invalid = @"
        {
            ""key"": ""key"",
            ""id"": ""id"",
            ""status"": ""status"",
            ""opts"": []
        }";

        DeserializeAndWriteToConsole(invalid);
    }

    private static void DeserializeAndWriteToConsole(string json)
    {
        RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, new OptsConverter());

        Console.WriteLine("key: " + root.key);
        Console.WriteLine("id: " + root.id);
        Console.WriteLine("status: " + root.status);
        if (root.opts != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("opts.start: " + root.opts.start);
            Console.WriteLine("opts.limit: " + root.opts.limit);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("opts: (null)");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Opts opts { get; set; }
}

public class Opts
{
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
key: key
id: id
status: status
opts.start: 42
opts.limit: 12

key: key
id: id
status: status
opts: (null)
```

Comment: Oh, this was just a generic example. Actually, I have more than 50 classes. So, I cannot use this approach to every single class. Anyway, thank's for help.